# C# WPF Binding to DataBase

Tags: c#, wpf, database, data-binding, binding

Hei all. If something would be not clear then please tell

I have dataGrid and TreeView. 
I have loaded data base as Entity Data Model and some tables.
One of these tables "relation" should show to the datagrid. But its (relation table) column depend of the other tables as system,model,function and device. In the Data grid should be 4 columns which contain names of these system,model,function and device. (the picture 1 as should be)

Problem in the how it all show. DataSource don't work well...  see picture 2.

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource relationsViewSource}">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="gridInventory" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="255,12,12,128" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        <StackPanel Height="391" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" DataContext="{StaticResource systemsViewSource}" >
            <TreeView Height="391" Name="treeView1" Width="239" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture2:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding both the `TreeView` and some of your `DataGrid` columns to an object, but not telling WPF how to draw the object. When WPF doesn't know how to draw an `object`, it by default draws it using a `TextBlock` with the `Text` bound to the object's `.ToString()`

You need to set the `ItemTemplate` to tell WPF how to draw your individual objects, such as this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

You could also use an implicit `DataTemplate` to tell WPF how to draw specific objects. This is just a DataTemplate that specifies a `DataType` without a `Key`, and WPF will use it anytime it tries to render an object of the specified type.

If you want to avoid removing `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` and manually specifying your DataGrid's columns, this is probably the method to use.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Device}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The TreeView you would need to set the Path on the Binding to the property you want to display,

The Devices is a collection and you need to put a Listview in there or something that will display a collection and then put a DataTemplate on it to display what you need, either that or bind to a converter to return a static string representation of the Device list

Or just get someone to do it all for you as seems the case on here lol